# Problem in continuous screencapturewithcursor in windows 7

Tags: c#

I have used follwing link and i am getting Desktopcapturewithmouse if it is working fine but After some time(10min) it showing GDI+ error....... and stopped to take screenshots....
My OS is windows 7. And same problem in Windows XP also

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/DesktopCaptureWithMouse.aspx

Please give me a solution to make it as continuously.....

Comment: at the very least we'll need to see the exception you're seeing and an excerpt from the code *where* it's occuring. However, please remember that **stackoverflow isn't technical support** it's for asking programming questions.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the comments on that CodeProject article? There seems to be a handle/memory leak in the `CaptureCursor` routine, at lease on of the comment posters also provides a reworked version that eliminates the leak.

Could this or someother memory leak be the problem you are facing?

Comment: There is no memory leak in  that .......  I have checked memory leak 
It shows after some times GDI+ Error